# how do i make my snake body parts to follow snake head at 90 degree

Tags: android

hi i am Rupesh and i developing a snake game in android in which i want my snake body must follow snake head at 90 degree following is the link from which i refer a code 
for snake movement 
[Click Here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,26736.)
    and here is code that i implementing to achieve snake movement

```
 if (SnakeActivity.this.isGoingRight) {
                    ImageView snakeHead = parts.get(0);
                    int snakeLength = parts.size() - 1;

                        for (int j = 0; j <= snakeLength; j++) {
                            if (j > 0) {
                                ImageView partBefore = parts.get(j - 1);
                                ImageView thisPart = parts.get(j);
      thisPart.setX((partBefore.getX() - (float) Math.cos(angle) * 30));
                                thisPart.setY((partBefore.getY() - (float)       Math.sin(angle) * 30));

                                thisPart.setRotation(90);

                            } else {
                                snakeHead.setX((float) (snakeHead.getX() +    speedX));
                                snakeHead.setRotation(90);
                                if (snakeHead.getX() + ((float)    snakeHead.getWidth()) >= ((float) SnakeActivity.this.screenWidth)) {
                                    snakeHead.setX(0.0f);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

this code is able to move snake its behavior is not that what i want .
that is snake body must follow snake head at 90 degree.
i am not getting that where i doing wrong please help me .
thank you in advance

Comment: also i have doubt that as i am using list data structure is it ok to use this data structure or i have to change it

Comment: (going back in my memory to the last time I wrote a snake-like game...) have you considered, on each frame of the UI refresh, to move the snake head forward (in whichever direction), add a snake body part where the snake head was, and then drop the "last" snake body part (ie: the tip of the tail)? I think that means the body parts don't have to be "moved" to follow the head, but simply appear and eventually disappear.